# Cannot convert from Type* to Type&&

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a simple class and I am using a std::vector to contain all of the instances of that class.  However when I do:

```
std::vector<MyType> v;
MyType m(1, 2, 3);
v.push_back(m);
```

Or if I do:

```
v.push_back(new MyType(1, 2, 3);
```

I get this error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MyType *' to 'MyType &&'
```

And if it is important, here my MyType code:

```
class MyType
{
public:
  int a;
  int b;
  float c;

MyType(int A, int B, float C)
{
    a = A;
    b = B;
    c = C;
}
};
```

I don't understand what is going wrong.

**EDIT:** My original (first snippet) of code works. For whatever reason I had to rebuild the solution and afterwards it compiled fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `MyType` is a type, while `m` is an object, so `new m(1,2,3)` doesn't even make sense.

Write:

```
v.push_back(MyType(1, 2, 3)); //without new
```

Instead of `push_back`, you could also use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) as :

```
v.emplace_back(1,2,3); //note there is no `MyType` now
```

`emplace_back` is preferable.

Comment: Why does my first code snippet in my question not work, it is the same thing as what you said.

Comment: @RiceNewman: As I said, it will not produce error, and will work. If it gives you error, you *must be* doing something else.

Comment: It is still giving me the error. It all started when I typed the very first code snippet from my question, which is equivalent to what you told me to use...

Comment: I guess I will try to rebuild the solution?

Comment: @RiceNewman: Try again and again. Also, check if it is exactly same. Or post your complete code in your question, or at ideone.com

Comment: @Nawaz Rebuilding the solution made my original code compile fine. I am new to Visual Studio, why would this be the case??? When do I know I need to rebuild?